# React-router with TypeScript, match parameters are always undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router

I want to do this kind of routing: `localhost:3000/function/page` where `function` tells the app which function should take care of this url, and `page` tells which part we are inside a specific function.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route component={SignUp} path="/signup/:page" />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

interface MatchProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
  page: string;
}

class SignUp extends React.Component<MatchProps> {
  public render(){
    console.log(this.props.page)
  }
}
```

Then I access this page via `localhost:3000/signup/1`, in console I can only get an `undefined` result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
import { match } from "react-router-dom";

interface DetailParams {
  id: string;
}

interface DetailsProps {
  required: string;
  match?: match<DetailParams>;
}


class Signup extends React.Component<DetailsProps, any> {
  render(){
    const match = this.props.match;
    console.log(match.params.page)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.props.match.params.page` instead of `this.props.page` solves the problem.

But it's still not perfect. `this.props.match.params.page` has a type as `any`. How can I restrict it.

Comment: I recommend asking follow-up questions by editing your post, or creating a new question.

Comment: @ggorlen sure. Thanks. I’m searching for existing answers first.